# How do you access an external lotusscript file

Tags: lotus-notes, file-permissions, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I'm reviewing a Lotus Notes application in my company. In some agent code, I saw lines like: `Use "Q:\external\exfile.lss"`. I cannot find these exfile.lss inside the database, so I assume that it is located somewhere in the server. How do you make an external lotusscript file accessible to a LN database? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you not answered your own question?

Answer (score 3):

When you use the Use syntax:

```
Use "Q:\external\exfile.lss"
```

the compiler will bring in that file content and compile it to object code. If you want to see the source you will need access to the original external file.

This technique can be used to protect access to the source code. Also to centralise the code as a means of source code management.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not

```
Use "Q:something.lss"
```

what you saw, but

```
%Include "Q:something.lss"
```

inside a script library.

Indeed it's used to hide the implementation of proprietary code. Which means that, if you don't have the file, you can't see nor change the implementation.

Comment: In other words... Find the original developer of this code and ask him what his mapping for the Q: drive was. That's where this particular piece of source code can be found.

Comment: So what you mean is that the compiled version of the external  lotusscript file is included in the Notes database?

Comment: Indeed, the source is not included.